# Get to underlying SQL for Cosmos DB Query generated via LINQ

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb, iqueryable, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating a query to cosmos using Linq

This is converted into SQL which is then run to do the search

```
var modelName = "Mondeo";
var baseQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Car>(StaticSettings.ProjectionsCollectionUri,
  new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = maxItemCount, PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) })
                .Where(order => car.ModelName == modelName);
```

If I run this code and put a breakpoint after this statement, I can see the raw SQL query generated

This is shown in the first line of the inspector

```
{{"query":"SQL HERE"}}
```

How can I get to this via code?

I am looking to get to this SQL to ensure that it is what I want it to be and I can use it in my tests

Paul

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio, the debugger by default would be showing you the output of `ToString()` in the inspector for any given object.

With that knowledge, you could retrieve that same query string object with the following code.

`var serializedQuery = baseQuery.ToString(); // "{{\"query\":\"SQL HERE\"}}"`

The result appears to be a serialized JSON object that wraps the actual SQL query. You can easily extract the SQL with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.1-beta1) using the following code.

`var sql = JObject.Parse(serializedQuery)["query"].Value<string>(); \\ "SQL HERE"`

**EDIT:** In current versions of the SDK, the solution would look like the following instead.

```
var baseQuery = container
               .GetItemLinqQueryable<Car>(
                    requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions
                    {
                        MaxItemCount = maxItemCount,
                        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
                    }
                )
               .Where(order => car.ModelName == modelName);

var sql = baseQuery.ToQueryDefinition().QueryText; // "SQL HERE"
```